# Email parsing using python thru NLP

Tags: python, email, nlp

I have written a python code to parse my email, but I want to write a code which is not centric to just one email. So I used regular expression to solve my problem. But when I need to extract addresses which can be written in any format or when I need to extract the Name of someone specific from the email (Ex: the name of the doctor specified or the name of the entity writing the email). And when I need to extract dates... I might have 2 dates mentioned (Ex: your appointment on 15/01 has been moved to 17/01). I want to extract the second date. In times of these I get stuck and my code becomes limited.
So, **PLEASE HELP ME WRITE A CODE WHICH IS NOT CENTRIC OR ATLEAST GUIDE ME TOWARDS A PROPER WAY**.

```
search_criteria = 'TEXT "Cityville Medical Clinic"'
status, email_ids = mail.search(None, search_criteria)

# Get the latest email (assuming it's the most relevant)
latest_email_id = email_ids[0].split()[-1]
status, email_data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, '(RFC822)')

# Extract the email text from the email message
email_message = email.message_from_bytes(email_data[0][1])
email_text = ''
for part in email_message.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
        email_text += part.get_payload()

# Load an NLP model (e.g., spaCy)
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
 
# Define regular expressions for extracting mobile numbers and dates

# Initialize lists to store extracted information
names = []
sender_names = []
sender_addresses = []
doctor_names = []
dates = []
times = []
addresses = []
mobile_numbers = []

# Extract information using spaCy and regex
doc = nlp(email_text)
# Extract sender addresses
mobile_pattern = r'(\d{10}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4})'
date_pattern =r'(?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s+\d{1,2}(?:st|nd|rd|th)?,\s+\d{4}|' \
              r'\d{1,2}(?:st|nd|rd|th)?\s+(?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December),\s+\d{4}|' \
              r'\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}'

time_pattern = r'\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s+[APap][Mm]'

# Define patterns for extracting specific information
#LOOK_HERE
name_pattern = r'Dear\s+(\w+)'


# Define patterns for extracting sender names and sender addresses
sender_name_pattern = r"Best regards,[\n\s]+([^\n]+)"
sender_address_pattern = r"Best regards,[\n\s]+([^\n]+)[\n\s]+([^\n]+)[\n\s]+([^\n]+)"
#LOOK HERE

doctor_name_pattern = r'with\s+(Dr\.\s+\w+)'
clinic_address_pattern = r'(\d+\s+[A-Za-z\s]+\s*,?\s*[A-Za-z\s]+\s*,?\s*\d{5})'
 
# Extract information using regex
name_match = re.search(name_pattern, email_text)
sender_name_match = re.search(sender_name_pattern, email_text)
sender_address_match = re.search(sender_address_pattern, email_text)
doctor_name_match = re.search(doctor_name_pattern, email_text)
clinic_address_match = re.search(clinic_address_pattern, email_text)
dates = re.findall(date_pattern, email_text)
times = re.findall(time_pattern, email_text)
mobile_numbers = re.findall(mobile_pattern, email_text)

# Print the extracted information
print("recipientName:", name_match.group(1) if name_match else "Not Found")
print("Sender Name:", sender_name_match.group(1) if sender_name_match else "Not Found")
print("Sender Address:", sender_address_match.group(2) if sender_address_match else "Not Found")
print("Doctor Name:", doctor_name_match.group(1) if doctor_name_match else "Not Found")
print("Clinic Address:", clinic_address_match.group(1) if clinic_address_match else "Not Found")
print("Appointment Date:", dates[0] if dates else "Not Found")
print("Appointment Time:", times[0] if times else "Not Found")
print("Mobile Number:", mobile_numbers[0] if mobile_numbers else "Not Found")`
```

Comment: Dear John,

I hope this email finds you well. We are writing to confirm your appointment with Dr. Smith on January 15th, 2023, at 2:00 PM. The appointment will take place at our clinic, located at 123 Main Street, Cityville, 45678.

Please remember to bring your insurance information and any relevant medical records. If you have any questions or need to reschedule, please contact our office at (555) 123-4567.

Best regards,
Jane Doe
Cityville Medical Clinic

Comment: The above is the email I tried to parse please help me write a code which is not centric to just this email